# Rosetta Stone Network V3 doesn't recognize built-in microphone in OSX Lion

Tags: osx-lion, microphone, rosetta-stone

I am using Rosetta Stone Network V3 on an early 2011 MacBook Pro running OSX Lion 10.7.3. When I log in, select a language and level, and then a lesson, I am prompted to select a microphone. The built in microphone doesn't show up, yet I've used it multiple times for other applications. I heard from another user that it doesn't work if headphones with a built-in microphone are used. I have not yet tried a USB microphone.

Is there some free work around to this? I would prefer to not have to buy a USB microphone, but if that is the only solution, then I'll live.

Edit: I noticed that Rosetta Stone tells me that if I don't have a microphone I should disable speech to move on, but that option is grayed out for me.

Comment: Well, *do* you have a headphone with a built-in microphone plugged in?

Comment: @slhck I attempted it without any headphones, then I attempted it with headphones with a microphone. The list is still blank regardless.

Answer (score 2):

I have had to purchase a USB headset. I have tried multiple sets on multiple Macs, with multiple OSs . . . . only way it works is with a USB headset. I picked up a couple for just $30 and they work fine, so you don't have to get one of the preimum sets to make it work.